# Advice: Set grub-reboot option while the computer is off

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, raspberry-pi, grub

I have a dual boot computer I've nicknamed Marcus.  I have written an Alexa app that invokes commands on a raspberry pi.

The Pi can start, reboot or power off Marcus.

I have a command that will issue log into Marcus, run grub-reboot and reboot the machine into windows. This obviously requires Marcus to be on and booted into Linux.

I would like to be able to set a variable that gets read by grub when it boots.  Seems like Vendor Keys might be an option.  I could make a file available to the network but it's not clear to me how I would have grub read it. And if I could have it read a network file could I use that to control which OS the system boots into.

Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when booting from network, the system firmware (either BIOS or UEFI) will provide network drivers. When booting from a local disk, the firmware-provided network drivers may not be activated, so GRUB would have to provide its own networking stack - unless it knows how to activate the firmware one (maybe with UEFI?). So is the Marcus system using BIOS or UEFI, and what type of NIC does it use?

Using the Vendor Keys feature of GRUB seems like a non-starter: it relies on reading a specific byte in the BIOS settings NVRAM to decide whether or not the special button was used. So you would need to somehow modify that value in between the system powering up and reaching GRUB. That implies running your own BIOS extension, a custom bootloader, and/or some sort of custom hardware.

---

The easiest way to implement this would probably be to set up the Marcus system to attempt booting from network, with the local boot as a second boot target in case the network boot fails. You would need to have a DHCP server that can provide the necessary DHCP options for PXE network booting, and a TFTP server that can provide the PXE bootloader and its configuration file to the Marcus system. The Pi could pretty easily do both of these things.

You might write two or three configuration files for the PXE bootloader running on Marcus: one for unconditionally booting Linux from the local disk, another for unconditionally booting Windows the same way, and perhaps a third for presenting a boot menu, for situations where the app is not running a start-up command (to eliminate the need to wait for the network boot attempt to time out when booting the system manually).

Your Alexa app would then simply change which of the configuration files is offered by the TFTP server, before sending the wake-up command to the Marcus system: according to the voice command used, it would place either the unconditional-Windows or unconditional-Linux boot configuration to the TFTP server, then trigger the wake-up or reboot command for the Marcus system. After waiting for enough time for the boot attempt to either succeed or time out (or after seeing a log message from the TFTP server indicating the configuration file was read, if you want to be fancy), it would restore the boot-menu configuration to the TFTP server.

Comment: This is super helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to write this response.  

So grub would be invoking the PXE functionality? Not my motherboard, correct?

Comment: Typically the motherboard's firmware would invoke the PXE functionality, and load the PXE bootloader (e.g. SYSLINUX or iPXE, or a GRUB image built specifically for PXE booting) from the TFTP server according to a pair of DHCP options. The PXE bootloader would then load its configuration file from the same TFTP server, and then chainload into GRUB, Windows bootloader, or whatever, on the local disk. GRUB's own networking support relies on the system firmware providing the actual network drivers. A legacy BIOS will do that only when you're actually booting from network.